# C# simple library project with OOP

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to make a simple software for a library. I've just started grasping the concepts of OOP in C# and I was told by one of my professors that it's good practice to have repository classes in your code so that the client code doesn't directly interact with the classes that deal with the data base. So I am trying to make a login/register forms work in Windows Forms but I'm having some problems.

```
public User GetByUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    User item = new User();
                    item.FirstName = sr.ReadLine();
                    item.LastName = sr.ReadLine();
                    item.Username = sr.ReadLine();
                    item.Password = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (item.Username == username && item.Password == password)
                    {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

My point is that I want to see if when I register a new user, if there is already another user with the same username and if there is, I want a messagebox to appear saying the same username cannot be used twice. How can I achieve this? How can I make the messagebox appear if the returned result is null and login the user when the result returns an object from the class User?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Tip, you can eliminate the `{` between your using statements.  They'll share the same `{ ... }`, and you reduce nesting slightly.

Comment: It would help to see the code (of your Form) that actually calls `GetByUsernameAndPassword` as well. Making the connection between the two parts will help solve the problem.

Comment: Your method returns `null` on failure, but there are at least two failure scenario's and it doesn't let calling code know which has occurred. I think it's useful to make this method less specific: instead of looking up users with a given username *and* password, make a method that only looks up users with a given username. That makes it useful in multiple scenario's: registration code can use it to determine if a username is already taken, login code can use it to determine if a user exists, and if so, if their password matches.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting to think about looking for duplicate usernames, I would suggest that you define a structure for your "database". At the minute, this looks to be a simple text file, but I can't see any provision for storing multiple users.

If your application will have a low user count, a text file may be fine, but it is important to define a format for it (for example, 1 user per line, properties are comma separated as a basic idea). If this is the case, I would suggest reading the whole file into RAM on startup and storing it in an IEnumerable type.

If your application will have a large user count (and I suspect that given the context, it won't), you may want to consider a proper database solution (something SQL-based perhaps) since you will quickly find that a text file becomes inefficient at this point.

Once you get this sorted, detecting duplicates becomes the easy bit. For example, if you had a list of User objects, you could:

```
private List<User> users;

internal bool DoesUsernameExist(string username)
{
    return (this.users.Where(x => x.Username == username).Count() > 0);
}
```

One other thing to note; it's probably not a good idea storing passwords in plain text. You probably want to look at hashing the passwords with an industry-standard hashing algorithm to protect them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: I'd use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`, because it stops iterating as soon as a match is found. `Count` has to iterate the full sequence. But if you're mostly looking up users by their username I'd use a `Dictionary<string, User>` instead of a `List<User>`.